# Yii2 Duplication of Model - row

Tags: php, logging, yii2, audit-trail

when a model attributes are edited or updated I do not want that record to updated. Instead a new record should be created and the old record should be disabled.
Also I have another log table where the old record is saved.

My code is given below

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{


  if ($insert) {
           // Да это новая запись (insert)
            $model = new Test3log();
            $model->desc = $this->desc ;
            $model->id_old = $this->id;
            $model->isdisabled=1;
            $model->save();
        } else {

            $save = "";
            foreach ($changedAttributes as $change => $val) {
                if (trim($val) != trim($this->{$change})) {
                    $save .= $this->attributeLabels()[$change] . '[' . $val . '->' . $this->{$change} . "]\n";
                }
            }
            $xx =$this->getoldattributes();
            if ($save != "") {
                 //  Get Old data
                 // Get New data
                 // repl new record with old id
                 // repl old record with new id
                $modelnewline = new Test3();
                $modelnewline->desc = $xx['desc'];
                $modelnewline->id_old = $xx['id'];
                $modelnewline->id = NULL;
                $modelnewline->isdisabled = 1;
                $modelnewline->save();
                $newid = $modelnewline->id;
                $oldid =$this->id;
                $this->isdisabled=1;
                $this->id = $newid;
                $this->desc = $changedAttributes['desc'];
                $this->save(false);

             }
        }
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above all, the problem you described needs to be implemented in your model's [`beforeSave()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#beforeSave()-detail) which is called at the beginning of inserting or updating a record, rather than `afterSave()` as your record will already be updated with the new values and you definitely don't want to do that.

As per your requirements.

> when a model attributes are edited or updated I do not want that
> record to be updated. Instead, a new record should be created and the old
> record should be disabled. Also, I have another log table where the old
> record is saved.

So there are 3 main things when attributes change for the existing record

- Disable the current record by updating status to 0.
- Add a new Record holding the new values.
- Add a new Record with the old values inside the backup or logs table.

I will not be adding the actual code as there isn't much information available regarding what models are interacted so looking at the requirements i will use the scenario where i will assume that i have books and whenever the name of the book is changed or updated it should add a new record with the new values and keep the old record as is changing the `status` column to `0` so that the book is disabled and backup the old values to `BooksBackup` table. So basically you will have a wireframe to adjust your code accordingly.

You can use the logic according to the models that you are using.

Below is the sample schema

- `Books` model
- `name varchar(255)`
- `status tinyint(1)`
- `BooksBackup` model
- `id int(11)`
- `book_id int(11)`
- `name varchar(255)`

I will add the following `beforeSave()` function in my `Books` Model

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if( !parent::beforeSave($insert) ){
        return false;
    }

    //your custom code
    if( !$insert ){

        $ifAttributesChanged = (!empty($this->dirtyAttributes) );

        //if attributes were changed
        if( $ifAttributesChanged ){

            //add new record with the new values
            $book = new self();
            $book->attributes = $this->attributes;
            $book->save();

            //add back the old values of the changed attributes 
            //to the current record so nothing is changed for the current record
            foreach( $this->dirtyAttributes as $attribute => $value ){
                $this->$attribute = $this->oldAttributes[$attribute];
            }

            //disable the current record
            $this->status = 0;

            //backup old record
            $backup = new BackupBooks();
            $backup->book_id = $this->id;
            $backup->name = $this->name;
            $backup->save();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad Omer Aslam I have found one issue.- if  Book had an PK then I have added a line $book->id = null; otherwise it will be an violation error. otherwise worked as a charm. Hopefully I can extend this solution to my related tables. thanks

Comment: sorry but i couldnt understand exactly what problem you are having, i tested this solution on my end and it works fine without any problem, @IgnatiusAbraham